# Unistall app on Android using adb on Mac

Tags: android, macos, adb

I tried adb unistall com.bla.ble but it doesn't working. It just shows me all those possible commands for adb without "Success" or "Fail - or whatever it returns, if adb can't unistall application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your spelling:

```
adb uninstall
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Mac,but I think the command should be adb uninstall packagename.

Is it just your typo?